# Create a symbolic link on Linux for a domain name

Tags: linux, web, dns, symlink

I need to create a symbolic link mysite.com to point to a directory /home/drupal/sites/mysite
Where do I cd into to create this? Do I need to run this command in /home/drupal/sites/mysite  or can I be anywhere on the server to do this?
Can this be done in the vhosts file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the directory where you want the link created:

```
ln -s /home/drupal/sites/mysite mysite.com
```

See:  http://frankmash.blogspot.com/2007/11/ln-s-examples.html